# Basic vector based drawing OOP design

Tags: php, object-oriented

I had an exercise as below for an interview. I've added my implementation at the end. How could I improve it?

## Exercise description:

> **Develop a simple vector based drawing package.**
>
> Your application should support the following 5 drawing primitives (we
>   will call them widget)
>
> 1) rectangle 2) square 3) ellipse 4) circle 5) textbox
>
> The application should allow a user to add a new widget to the
>   drawing, stating the location and size / shape of the widget. The
>   location can be a standard x/y coordinate on an imaginary page. The
>   size/shape depends on the widget, as follows:
>
> - rectangle - width and height
> - square - width
> - ellipse - horizontal and vertical diameter
> - circle - diameter
> - textbox - bounding rectangle (i.e, the rectangle which surronds the textbox; the text will be centred within this rectangle)
>
> Notes:
>
> - you don't need to actually render the widgets in any manner - we're just simulating a drawing package at this stage
> - your application can add a hard coded  set of widgets to the drawing at the bootstrap, no real user input. Please add one of each
>     widget to the drawing.

---

## My implementation:

**bootstrap.php**

```
/*
* rectangle x=10, y=10, width=30, height=40
*/
$renderEngine = new CliRenderer();
$renderEngine->render("
-------------------------------\n
Current drawing\n
------------------------------\n
");
$rectangle = new WidgetFactory(new Widget(10,10), new Rectangle(30, 40), $renderEngine);
$rectangle->draw();
/*
* square x=15, y=30, size=35
 */
$square = new WidgetFactory(new Widget(15, 30), new Square(35), $renderEngine);
$square->draw();
/*
* ellipse x=100, y=150, horizontal diameter=300, vertical diameter=200
*/

$ellipse = new WidgetFactory(new Widget(100, 150), new Elipse(300, 200), $renderEngine);
$ellipse->draw();
/**
* circle x=1, y=1, size=300
*/
$circle = new WidgetFactory(new Widget(1,1), new Square(300), $renderEngine);
$circle->draw();
/*
* textbox x=5, y=5, width=200, height=100, text="sample text"
*/
$textBox = new WidgetFactory(new Widget(5,5), new TextBox(200, 100, "sample text"), $renderEngine);
$textBox->draw();
$renderEngine->render("------------------------------");
```

**RenderEngineInterface.php**

```
<?php

interface RenderEngineInterface
{
    public function render($str);
}
```

**CliRenderer.php**

```
<?php

class CliRenderer implements RenderEngineInterface
{

    public function render($str)
    {
        echo $str."\n";
    }

}
```

**WidgetFactory.php**

```
<?php


class WidgetFactory
{

    private $widget;

    private $shape;

    private $renderEngine;

    function __construct(WidgetInterface $widget,ShapeInterface $shape,RenderEngineInterface $renderEngine)
    {
        $this->widget = $widget;
        $this->shape = $shape;
        $this->renderEngine = $renderEngine;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        return $this->renderEngine->render($this->shape->output($this->widget));
    }


}
```

**WidgetInterface.php**

```
<?php
interface WidgetInterface
{

    public function getX();
    public function getY();
}
```

**Widget.php**

```
class Widget implements WidgetInterface
{
    private $x;

    private $y;

    function __construct($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getX()
    {
        return $this->x;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $x
     */
    public function setX($x)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getY()
    {
        return $this->y;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $y
     */
    public function setY($y)
    {
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}
```

**ShapeInterface.php**

```
<?php

interface ShapeInterface
{
    public function output(WidgetInterface $widget);
}
```

**Circle.php**

```
<?php


class Circle implements ShapeInterface
{

    private $size;

    function __construct($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $size
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }


    public function output(WidgetInterface $widget)
    {
        return "circle (".$widget->getX().",".$widget->getY().") size=".$this->size;
    }

}
```

**Elipse.php**

```
<?php


class Elipse implements ShapeInterface
{

    private $diameterH;
    private $diameterV;

    function __construct($diameterH, $diameterV)
    {
        $this->diameterH = $diameterH;
        $this->diameterV = $diameterV;
    }


    public function output(WidgetInterface $widget)
    {
        return "ellipse (".$widget->getX().",".$widget->getY().") horizontal diameter=".$this->diameterH.", vertical diameter=".$this->diameterV;
    }

}
```

**Rectangle.php**

```
<?php
class Rectangle implements ShapeInterface
{

    private $width;

    private $height;

    function __construct($width,$height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $height
     */
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $width
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function output(WidgetInterface $widget)
    {
        return "rectangle (".$widget->getX().",".$widget->getY().") width=".
        $this->width." height=".$this->height;
    }

}
```

**Square.php**

```
<?php

class Square implements ShapeInterface
{

    private $size;

    function __construct($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $size
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }


    public function output(WidgetInterface $widget)
    {
        return "square (".$widget->getX().",".$widget->getY().") size=".$this->size;
    }

}
```

**TextBox.php**

```
<?php

class TextBox implements ShapeInterface
{

    private $width;

    private $height;

    private $text;

    function __construct($width,$height, $text)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $height
     */
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $text
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $width
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function output(WidgetInterface $widget)
    {
        return "textbox (".$widget->getX().",".$widget->getY().") width=".
        $this->width." height=".$this->height;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written lots of code. I would have preferred a lighter API. Something like this:

```
<?php

class Canvas {
    private $commands = [];

    public function moveTo($x, $y) {
        return $this->add("M $x $y");
    }

    public function square($width) {
        return $this->rectangle($width, $width);
    }

    public function rectangle($width, $height) {
        return $this->add("h $width v $height h -$width v -$height");
    }

    public function ellipse($hradius, $vradius) {
        return $this->add("TODO: some SVG commands for an ellipse($hradius, $vradius)");
    }

    public function circle($radius) {
        return $this->ellipse($radius, $radius);
    }

    public function textBox($width, $height, $text) {
        $this->rectangle($width, $height);
        return $this->add("\"$text\" tj"); // OK, this is a PDF operator, not SVG
    }

    public function draw() {
        return implode("\n", $this->commands);
    }

    private function add($command) {
        $this->commands[] = $command;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The point is that the actual drawing was not part of the exercise. And if you have a little luck you have to draw it to a PDF or PostScript file or an SVG file, in which case you don't need a class per graphic primitive since you can generate the rendering code directly.

Using this canvas class is easy:

```
print((new Canvas())
    ->moveTo(10, 10)->rectangle(60, 30)
    ->moveTo(10, 50)->square(40)
    ->moveTo(10, 90)->ellipse(10, 30)
    ->moveTo(10, 90)->circle(20)
    ->moveTo(10, 130)->textBox(70, 10, "Hello, world")
    ->draw());
```

As long as the users of this canvas class don't need to manipulate the graphic primitives, there is no need to make the API more complicated than this.

I have [implemented](https://github.com/misakuo/svgtoandroid/blob/master/src/com/moxun/s2v/utils/SVGPathBuilder.java) exactly this idea [in a practical project](https://github.com/misakuo/svgtoandroid/blob/master/src/com/moxun/s2v/utils/SVGAttrParser.java), and it works great there.